# Translation from raw pointer to boost::shared_ptr: tree implementation with share_from_this

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, smart-pointers

this is most likely a beginners question.
I implemented a basic version of a tree, nodes are stored in class A. every A has exact one parent (except the root node) and a vector of children. With raw pointers everything works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class A
{
private:
    class A* parent;

    std::vector<class  A*> children;

    std::vector<int> storage;
public:
    std::vector<int>& getStorage();

    void connect(A* child);

    std::vector<A*>& getChildren();

    void addStorage(int& i);

    A();

    A(A* par);
};


class B
{
private:
    A* root;
public:

    B();

    A*&  getRoot();
};

void A::addStorage(int& i)
{
    storage.push_back(i);
}

std::vector<int>&
A::getStorage()
{
    return storage;
}

B::B()
{
    A* a_1_2 = new A;
    root = a_1_2;
    //A* ptr1 = new A;
    //*ptr1 = root;
    A* a_2_3  = new A(a_1_2);
    //A* ptr2 = new A;
    //*ptr2 = a_2_3;
    A* a_2_13 = new A(a_1_2);
    //A* ptr3 = new A;
    //*ptr3 = a_2_13;
    A* a_13_14 = new A(a_2_13);
    //A* ptr4 = new A;
    //*ptr4 = a_13_14;
    A* a_13_24 = new A(a_2_13);
    int i =1;
    int j =2;
    int k =3;
    a_13_24->addStorage(i);
    a_13_24->addStorage(j);
    a_13_24->addStorage(k);

    //A* ptr5 = new A;
    //*ptr5 = a_13_24;
    A* a_2_13_b = root->getChildren().at(1);
    std::cout << "inside constructor root size"<< root->getChildren().size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "inside constructor 2.child size"<< a_2_13_b->getChildren().size() << "\n";
}

A*&
B::getRoot()
{
    return root;
}

std::vector<A*>&
A::getChildren()
{

    return children;
}

A::A(A* par)
{
    parent = par;
    par->connect(this);
}

A::A()
{

}

void
A::connect(A* child)
{
    children.push_back(child);
}

int main()
{
    B tree;
    std::cout << "inside main root size"<< tree.getRoot()->getChildren().size()<< "\n";
    A* a_2_13_b = tree.getRoot()->getChildren().at(1);
    A* a_13_24_b = a_2_13_b->getChildren().at(1);
    std::cout << "inside main 2.child size"<< a_2_13_b->getChildren().size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "inside main leave storage"<< a_13_24_b->getStorage().size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This was my first step in my first program. I wanted to convert the raw pointers into boost shared pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
class A : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
private:
     boost::shared_ptr<A> parent;

    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> > children;

    std::vector<int> storage;
public:
    std::vector<int>& getStorage();

    void connect();

    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> >& getChildren();

    void addStorage(int& i);

    A();

    A(boost::shared_ptr<A> par);
};


class B
{
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<A> root;
public:

    B();

    boost::shared_ptr<A>&  getRoot();
};

void A::addStorage(int& i)
{
    storage.push_back(i);
}

std::vector<int>&
A::getStorage()
{
    return storage;
}

B::B()
{
    A* a_1_2 = new A;
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_1(a_1_2);
    root = ptr_1;
    //A* ptr1 = new A;
    //*ptr1 = root;
    A* a_2_3  = new A(ptr_1);
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_2(a_2_3);
    ptr_2->connect();
    //A* ptr2 = new A;
    //*ptr2 = a_2_3;
    A* a_2_13 = new A(ptr_1);
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_3(a_2_13);
    ptr_3->connect();
    //A* ptr3 = new A;
    //*ptr3 = a_2_13;
    A* a_13_14 = new A(ptr_3);
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_4(a_13_14);
    ptr_4->connect();
    //A* ptr4 = new A;
    //*ptr4 = a_13_14;
    A* a_13_24 = new A(ptr_3);

    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_5(a_13_24);
    ptr_5->connect();
    int i =1;
    int j =2;
    int k =3;
    ptr_5->addStorage(i);
    ptr_5->addStorage(j);
    ptr_5->addStorage(k);

    //A* ptr5 = new A;
    //*ptr5 = a_13_24;
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a_2_13_b = root->getChildren().at(1);
    std::cout << "inside constructor root size"<< root->getChildren().size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "inside constructor 2.child size"<< a_2_13_b->getChildren().size() << "\n";
}

boost::shared_ptr<A>&
B::getRoot()
{
    return root;
}

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> >&
A::getChildren()
{

    return children;
}

A::A(boost::shared_ptr<A> par)
{
    parent = par;
    //par->connect();
}

A::A()
{

}

void
A::connect()
{

    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> > childs = parent->getChildren();
    childs.push_back(shared_from_this());
}

int main()
{
    B tree;
    std::cout << "inside main root size"<< tree.getRoot()->getChildren().size()<< "\n";
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a_2_13_b  = tree.getRoot()->getChildren().at(1);
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a_13_24_b = a_2_13_b->getChildren().at(1);
    std::cout << "inside main 2.child size"<< a_2_13_b->getChildren().size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "inside main leave storage"<< a_13_24_b->getStorage().size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The root node already has no children, so the following line

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> a_2_13_b = root->getChildren().at(1);
```

gives:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't understand this, as when I create the roots child nodes, I invoke connect(), which should store the child in its parents (this is here the root) children.

Edit:
The working solution thanks to the help:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
class A : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
private:
     boost::weak_ptr<A> parent;

    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> > children;

    std::vector<int> storage;
public:
    std::vector<int>& getStorage();

    void connect();

    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> >& getChildren();

    void addStorage(const int& i);

    A();

    A(boost::weak_ptr<A> par);
};


class B
{
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<A> root;
public:

    B();

    boost::shared_ptr<A>&  getRoot();
};

void A::addStorage(const int& i)
{
    storage.push_back(i);
}

std::vector<int>&
A::getStorage()
{
    return storage;
}

B::B()
{
    //A a_1_2;
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_1= boost::make_shared<A>();
    root = ptr_1;

    //A a_2_3 (ptr_1);
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_2= boost::make_shared<A>(ptr_1);
    ptr_2->connect();

    //A a_2_13 (ptr_1);
    boost::shared_ptr<A>ptr_3 = boost::make_shared<A>(ptr_1);
    ptr_3->connect();

    //A a_13_14 (ptr_3);
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_4= boost::make_shared<A>(ptr_3);
    ptr_4->connect();

    //A a_13_24 (ptr_3);
    boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_5= boost::make_shared<A>(ptr_3);
    ptr_5->connect();

    ptr_5->addStorage(1);
    ptr_5->addStorage(2);
    ptr_5->addStorage(3);


    boost::shared_ptr<A> a_2_13_b = root->getChildren().at(1);
    std::cout << "inside constructor root size"<< root->getChildren().size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "inside constructor 2.child size"<< a_2_13_b->getChildren().size() << "\n";
}

boost::shared_ptr<A>&
B::getRoot()
{
    return root;
}

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> >&
A::getChildren()
{

    return children;
}

A::A(boost::weak_ptr<A> par)
{
    parent = par;
    //par->connect();
}

A::A()
{

}

void
A::connect()
{
    auto par = parent.lock();
    //std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> > childs = par->getChildren();
    par->getChildren().push_back(shared_from_this());
}

int main()
{
    B tree;
    std::cout << "inside main root size"<< tree.getRoot()->getChildren().size()<< "\n";
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a_2_13_b  = tree.getRoot()->getChildren().at(1);
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a_13_24_b = a_2_13_b->getChildren().at(1);
    std::cout << "inside main 2.child size"<< a_2_13_b->getChildren().size() << "\n";
    std::cout << "inside main leave storage"<< a_13_24_b->getStorage().size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have circular references, a parent cannot own its children and the children also own the parent. Could the link back to the parent just be a raw (i.e. non-owning) pointer? Or use a `weak_ptr<A>` to break the cycle

Comment: Also you should stop using raw pointers to hold your objects, just give the raw pointer **immediately** to a `shared_ptr` or better yet, use `boost::make_shared<A>(ptr_n)`

Comment: Do the children really need to be pointers? You could make the tree own its children, and use a container of incompete types, such as `boost::container::vector<A>`.

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely will follow also your hint to give the raw pointer immediately to shared ptr, but first trying to implement the parent as weak pointer. To have access to its underlying object (class A member) a quick look in the api gave me the lock function to convert into a shared pointer temporarily. This gives exact same error as before, maybe because for this short time I have again a cycle?

Comment: Have you read my answer below? It addresses the error rather than the more general design issue about ownership cycles.

Comment: Regarding the "working solution": `boost::make_shared<A>(*(new A));` -- good lord, no! Just use `boost::make_shared<A>()` or `boost::make_shared<A>(ptr_3)`, don't create an object on the heap then copy it and leak it!

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely Well I have to admit, this answer is beyond my knowledge. My knowledge is, that I have to use new to make my A's exist also outside B constructor. This gives me a pointer, i.e. A* a_1_2 = new A;  now I want to convert this raw pointer to a smart pointer leading then to boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr_1= boost::make_shared<A>(a_1_2); This should be the same in two lines like the one line I wrote? I have absolutely no clue, how to instance an A on the heap directly with a smart pointer. I can construct an A and then use make_shared, but then its does not point to heap and will vanish

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely think I was wrong, seems i do not need to call new with smart pointers at all? At least the again updated version works and I have no raw pointers any more. Not sure if this is right now.

Comment: Right, `make_shared<A>(args...)` is equivalent to `shared_ptr<A>(new A(args...))` so you should not be passing an `A` to `make_shared`, you pass the constructor arguments for `A` and let `make_shared` create the `A` internally from those arguments. What you had before is equivalent to `shared_ptr<A>(new A(*(new A)))` which is just crazy

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely Thanks a lot, hopefully I got it now and updated right the "running example".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a reference:

```
void
A::connect()
{

    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<A> > childs = parent->getChildren();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise you just connect the child to a local copy of the vector and then throw that away. You never add it to the parent's own vector.

Instead of using a reference you could just add it directly:

```
  parent->getChildren().push_back(shared_from_this());
```

Also why does `A::addStorage(int&)` require a non-const reference when all it does is copy it?  Make it `A::addStorage(int)` and the rest of `B::B()` gets simpler too:

```
    ptr_5->addStorage(1);
    ptr_5->addStorage(2);
    ptr_5->addStorage(3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. About your second suggestion, isn't A::addStorage(const int& i) even better than your suggestion? Can use the same calls, and the compiler does one less copy? Would be glad if you could look again in the edited question where I will now put the working code at the end.

Comment: Copying an `int` is cheaper than passing by reference.

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely Thanks for the info, but in my real case scenario I dont pass ints, I pass a struct (pcl::modelcoefficients) which consisits of 7 floats. I guess the cheapness does not hold for this case?

Comment: In that case it's probably better to pass by const-reference